# Gets stops processing script if it encounters a apostrophe

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm futzing with a lesson over on Codecademy, pretty basic but the lesson prompts the user for a string and then prompts them for words to hide from the string. I've already finished with the lesson but I wanted to try messing with it outside of the lesson.

What I'm finding is the following script will run to completion in the lesson's scripting and interpreter area but if I try to run the same script over at say labs.codecademy.com or repl.it
I'll get prompted for the first question and if I enter a string containing an apostrophe it won't go on to the next prompt. I'm not getting an error, but eventually I'll get a "This program is taking too long to finish" pop up.

Here's the script:

```
puts "Tell me something."
    text = gets.chomp
puts "What would you like me to forget?"
    redact = gets.chomp

words = text.split(" ")  

words.each { |text|
     if redact.include? text
        print "REDACTED "
     else
        print text + " "
     end
}
```

So for example if you were to enter *I really like blueberry pie* that passes, but if you were to enter *They've told me I should try the blueberry pie* the program gets hung up.

I'm a complete novice when it comes to Ruby, but is there a way to have gets process that sort of punctuation? Or is that not the right way to go about it? Or is it just the environment I'm trying to run this program in?

Comment: It's probably waiting for the matching closing quote even if your intention is an apostrophe.

Comment: so what IS the environment you are running in? i can't see anything that would indicate this behavior.

Comment: @phoet I have no idea about the environment. Again I'm a newbie with all this. but I definitely tried it over at http://repl.it/languages/Ruby and got the same message about the program taking too long.

Comment: @Danielle - or they both are running on the same js engine which has this bug. It is working fine on my machine. Btw. are you working on windows? There are some strange whitespacing issues with your code.

Comment: @BroiSatse Yeah I am working on windows (8.1 to be exact). You know I didn't even think of that. I figured since they were run by two different sites that it was definitely on my end. Is there a better place to test scripts? I'm assuming one option is locally but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Danielle - you need to install ruby o your machine, save the script in `rb` file and run it with `ruby <path_to_file>` however running ruby on windows is pretty painful. If you are not yet decided to switch OS for UNIX have a go with windows ruby installers: http://rubyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 0):

`IO.gets` is a system-level call: http://apidock.com/ruby/IO/gets

it well read from STDIN (standard input) which is the text that you type in a terminal window: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

browsers per-se don't have this and it might depend on the implementation of the web-based console about how they handle calls like that. usually, there are known limitations (like this one).

as @BroiStatse pointed out, it might as well be a bug in in their browser-based implementation.